Continuous maps between Peano continua
A Peano continuum is a compact connected metrizable space which is locally connected. It is called nondegenerate if it has more than one point.
Denote by $C(X,Y)$ the space of all continuous maps from $X$ to $Y$. By the Hahn-Mazurkiewicz theorem, every Peano continuum is a continuous image of $I=[0,1]$. Also, e.g. by the classical result, that every separable metrizable space can be embedded to the Hilbert cube $I^\omega$, it follows, that every nondegenerate Peano continuum can be continuously mapped onto $I$. Using that we can deduce that for nondegenerate Peano continua $X, Y$, the spaces $C(X, I)$ and $C(I, Y)$ are quite rich and consequently the space $C(X,Y)$ (considered with the uniform topology) is quite rich. However, I do not know the answer to the following question.
Questions: Are the following conditions true for all nondegenerate Peano continua $X, Y$?

The point $id\in C(X,X)$ is not isolated.
The space $C(X,Y)$ does not contain an isolated point.
$\forall f\in C(X,Y)\quad \forall \varepsilon>0\quad \exists g\in C(X,Y):$
\begin{align*}  |g-f|<\varepsilon\quad \And\quad g \text{ is locally constant on a dense open set}.
\end{align*}

Note: A map $g\in C(X,Y)$ is locally constant on a dense open set means that there is an open dense set $U\subseteq X$ such that for every $x\in U$ there is some open set $V\subseteq U$ containing $x$, such that $f|V$ is constant.
Note: With some small effort it can be proved that 3.$\implies$ 2. $\implies$ 1.
Note: I can prove that if $X, Y$ are one-dimensional, then the answers are positive.

How should I read "2 implies 1"?
"If for some $Y$ the space $C(X,Y)$ does not have an isolated point, then $C(X,X)$ does not have one"? Or "If for all $Y$ $\ldots$"?

This isn't particularly helpful but $1$ and $2$ are true for all Peano continua if $C(X,Y)$ is equipped with the pointwise convergence topology instead

The implication $2. \implies 1.$ is uprecisely stated, what I mean is that it holds for $X=Y$ trivially.

Here's a minor observation. $2$ holds whenever one of $X,Y$ is contractible. Similarly, if $X$ is an ANR and $Y$ is weakly contractible, or if $Y$ is an ANR and $X$ has trivial shape. In all these cases $C(X,Y)$ is arc connected. On the other hand, $2$ also holds in case $\dim X\leq n$ and $Y$ is LC$^n$. For instance, when $Y$ is locally contractible and $\dim X<\infty$.
